# Why am I NOT able to interact with ALL of my smart contract functions via my HTML GUI?

Tags: remix, javascript, web3-providers, solidity-0.8.x

I have noticed something very strange...

I have a smart contract with two functions. I am able to interact with all of them (In Remix, Web3 Provider Environment, pragma solidity ^0.8.2) perfectly well. However, when I try calling the same functions via my Dapp (HTML GUI), I am **ONLY** able to interact with **ONE** of my functions, and **NOT** with the other.

Please help me understand what is going on.

Find below a snippet of my solidity functions:

```
    struct CryptoGift {
    address from;
    address to;
    uint256 tokenId;
    string  tokenName;
    string  messageToRecipient;
    uint256 createdAt;
    uint256 firstReminderAt;
    uint256 transferDate;
}
  
CryptoGift[] private allGifts;
mapping(address => CryptoGift[]) private myGifts;

function viewAllGifts() public view returns ( CryptoGift[] memory ) {   
    return allGifts;   
}

function viewMyGifts() public view returns ( CryptoGift[] memory ) {        
    return myGifts[msg.sender];
}
```

In Remix, using **ENVIRONENT:** Web3 Provider
**ACCOUNT:** 0xb35abE6Cbf39AF6b547dB36C4645140F1d807413, both functions `viewAllGifts` and `viewMyGifts` work perfectly as illustrated below:

[image: illustrating that both functions work in the Remix environment]

However, in my HTML file, the `viewAllGifts` works perfectly while the `viewMyGifts` doesn't work.

Find below a snippet from my `viewMyGifts` function in **javascript**:

```
contractMethods.viewMyGifts().call( ({}), (error, result)=> {
    console.log("Your in viewMyGifts"); 
    console.log("ethAddress: " +ethAddress);
    console.log("Result: " +result);
    console.log("Error: " +error);
  if(!error){ }
  else{}
});
```

The above code yeilds:

```
Your in viewMyGifts
ethAddress: 0xb35abe6cbf39af6b547db36c4645140f1d807413
Result: 
Error: null
```

While...

```
contractMethods.viewAllGifts().call( ({}), (error, result)=> {
    console.log("Your in viewAllGifts"); 
    console.log("ethAddress: " +ethAddress);
    console.log("Result: " +result);
    console.log("Error: " +error);
  if(!error){ }
     else{}
 });



Your in viewAllGifts
ethAddress: 0xb35abe6cbf39af6b547db36c4645140f1d807413
Result: 0xb35abE6Cbf39AF6b547dB36C4645140F1d807413,0x22Eb94E0DD34B70B9E718595D71bF5CF3065b1c4,100,BOO,I love you Boo 0,0,1652339951,1652339981,1652340011,0xb35abE6Cbf39AF6b547dB36C4645140F1d807413,0x22Eb94E0DD34B70B9E718595D71bF5CF3065b1c4,101,BOO,I love you Boo 1,0,1652339957,1652339987,1652340017,0xb35abE6Cbf39AF6b547dB36C4645140F1d807413,0x22Eb94E0DD34B70B9E718595D71bF5CF3065b1c4,102,BOO,I love you Boo 2,0,1652339962,1652339992,1652340022,0xb35abE6Cbf39AF6b547dB36C4645140F1d807413,0x22Eb94E0DD34B70B9E718595D71bF5CF3065b1c4,103,BOO,I love you Boo 3,0,1652339967,1652339997,1652340027
app.js:36 Error: null
```

Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're using `msg.sender` in a `view` function.

This variable is used for transactions, but on read-only functions it's possible that `msg.sender` will be empty.

Change your function to -

```
function viewMyGifts(address account) public view returns ( CryptoGift[] memory ) {        
    return myGifts[account];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. In response to your answer, you can use `msg.sender` in `view`/ read-only functions, the reason I am using it is merely to filter the results to reflect transactions that belong to the wallet holder /`msg.sender`, whereas the `viewAllGifts()` reflected the entire list of transactions that were unfiltered.

Furthermore, if the wallet holder /`msg.sender` doesn't own any transactions then it should rightfully be empty

Comment: Msg.sender is empty in view functions since they’re called without firing a transaction, hence no sending wallet. No need for private key, so no wallet. Does this answer your question?

Comment: On the contrary, msg.sender is NOT empty in view functions. Try out my solution, it actually works!

Comment: That's because you're using hardhat / truffle... it will be empty when you deploy to production and call the method externally. `msg.sender` is not empty only if you (in hardhat) attach a wallet to the contract, but since it's not mandatory for the call, `msg.sender` should not be used on `view` functions. As mentioned in my answer, it's **possible** that msg.sender will be empty.

Comment: I appreciate your valuable contribution, as I had no idea it works differently in production. I will definitely update my code to reflect your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I feel kind of stupid X-D because the solution was so simple...

The solution, since it's an asynchronous method, was (yes you guessed it) to simply wrap the function in an Async/await as illustrated in the code below.

```
async function generateTheviewMyGiftsTiles (){
  await contractMethods.viewAllGifts().call( ({}), (error, result)=> {
    console.log("Your in viewAllGifts"); 
    console.log("ethAddress: " +ethAddress);
    console.log("Result: " +result);
    console.log("Error: " +error);

    if(!error){ }
    else{}
  });
}
```

The code above now yields the desired results.

The reason I wasn't getting any yields in the original code was merely because the compiler would call the `contractMethods.viewAllGifts().call()` function, but wouldnt wait for a any results and merely continue on to the next function. While wrapping the `contractMethods.viewAllGifts().call()` in an async/await forces the compiler to wait for the results of `contractMethods.viewAllGifts().call()` before continuing on to the next function.